# Field x not found in table due to a dataset containing tables with and without the field

Tags: field, structure, google-bigquery

I have a dataset containing daily tables.

Starting at a given date, I generated a new field x in these tables.

Now I would like to query the full dataset with a where clause using this new field.
Example:

```
SELECT field1 FROM
TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT([mytable], DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2016-01-11"), -7, "DAY"), TIMESTAMP("2016-01-11") )
WHERE x != null
```

Unfortunately, I get `Field x not found in table mytable20160105`, because indeed this table does not have this field.

Would there be a way, without updating the structure of my old tables, to query all of them and filtering on this field? i.e. for BigQuery to consider that if the field is not defined, the field should be 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have one schema for time between 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-04 and then you added extra/new 'x' field since 2016-01-05

below type of query would solve your question

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT([mytable], TIMESTAMP("2016-01-05"), TIMESTAMP("2016-01-07"))
  ),
  (SELECT * FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT([mytable], TIMESTAMP("2016-01-01"), TIMESTAMP("2016-01-04")),
  )
WHERE NOT x IS NULL
```

At the same time above query in this particulat case doesn't make much sense as you would know in advance that second subquery doesn't have any result so you would use rather below:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT([mytable], TIMESTAMP("2016-01-05"), TIMESTAMP("2016-01-07")
WHERE NOT x IS NULL
```

But I hope your example in question is just simplified example so hopefuly first option still makes sense to you and you can make use of it

Meantime, one time patching your tables with old schema is preferable. It is cost free so why not? Check [Tables Patch API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch)

Comment: Thanks, indeed my query was a simplified one.

Comment: I wish BigQuery had a simpler solution to this problem. For example a way to consider non existing column as NULL values.

Comment: you can submit your proposals to google team here - https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list